# Calling locals() in a function not intuitive?

Tags: python, locals

This may be elementary, but may help me understand namespaces.
 A good explanation might step through what happens when the 
 function *definition* is executed, and then what happens later 
 when the function *object* is executed.
 Recursion may be complicating things.

The results aren't obvious to me; I would have expected:

locals_1 would contain var;
   locals_2 would contain var and locals_1;   and
   locals_3 would contain var, locals_1, and locals_2

```
# A function calls locals() several times, and returns them ...
def func():
  var = 'var!'
  locals_1 = locals()
  locals_2 = locals()
  locals_3 = locals()
  return locals_1, locals_2, locals_3

# func is called ...
locals_1, locals_2, locals_3 = func()

# display results ...
print 'locals_1:', locals_1
print 'locals_2:', locals_2
print 'locals_3:', locals_3
```

Here are the results:

```
locals_1: {'var': 'var!', 'locals_1': {...}, 'locals_2': {...}}
locals_2: {'var': 'var!', 'locals_1': {...}, 'locals_2': {...}}
locals_3: {'var': 'var!', 'locals_1': {...}, 'locals_2': {...}}
```

The pattern seems to be, with (n) calls to *locals*, all of
 the returned locals-dicts are identical, and they all include
 the first (n-1) locals-dicts.

Can someone explain this?

More specifically:

Why does locals_1 include itself?

Why does locals_1 include locals_2? Is locals_1 assigned when
   *func* is created, or executed?

And why is locals_3 not included anywhere?

Does "{...}" indicate an 'endless recursion'? Sort of like 
   those photos of mirrors facing each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My original question settles down to, 'just *what is* `locals()`?'
Here's my current (speculative) understanding, written in Pythonese:

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

## What is the nature of Python's locals() ?

Every local namespace has it's own namespace-table, which can be
viewed *in total* using the **`locals`** built-in function.
(A **namepace-table**, in effect, is like a dict that holds **"identifier":  object** entries; for each item, the key is the name (in string-form) assigned (or 'bound') to the object.)

When called in a non-global level, `locals` returns the interpreter's sole representation of the *current* local namespace-table: a 'dynamic', always-up-to-date, specialized, dict-like object.

It's not a simple dict, nor is it the actual name-table, but it's effectively 'alive', and is instantly updated from the live table anytime it is referenced (when tracing is on, it updates with every statement).
On exiting the scope, this object vanishes, and is created anew for the current scope whenever `locals` is next called.

(When called in a global (modular) level, `locals` instead returns **`globals()`**, Python's global-namespace representation, which may have a different nature).

So, `L = locals()` binds the name `L` to this 'stand-in' for the local namespace-table; subsequently, anytime `L` is referenced, this object is refreshed and returned.
And, any additional names bound (in the same scope) to `locals()` will be *aliases* for this same object.

Note that `L`, being assigned to `locals()`, necessarily becomes an 'infinite recursion' object (displayed as the dict `{...}`), which may or may not be important to you. You can make a simple dict *copy* of `L` at any time, however.
Some attributes of `locals()`, such as **`keys`**, also return simple objects.

To capture a 'pristine' snapshot of locals() within a function, use a technique that doesn't make any local assignments; for example, pass the copy as argument to a function, that pickles it out to a file.

There are particulars about `L`, and how it behaves; it includes free variables from the blocks of functions, but not classes, and, the docs warn against trying to alter `L`'s contents (it may no longer 'mirror' the name-table).
It perhaps should only be read (copied, etc.)

(Why `locals()` is designed to be 'live', rather than a 'snapshot', is another topic).

In summary:

**`locals()`** is a unique, specialized object (in dict-form); it's Python's *live* representation of the current local namespace-table (not a frozen snapshot)

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

A way to get the results I had expected, then, is to produce *copies* of `locals()` (here using dict.copy), at each step:

```
# A function copies locals() several times, and returns each result ...
def func():
    var = 'var!'
    locals_1 = locals().copy()
    locals_2 = locals().copy()
    locals_3 = locals().copy()
    return locals_1, locals_2, locals_3
```

*func* is called, and the returns are displayed:

```
locals_1: {'var': 'var!'}
locals_2: {'var': 'var!', 'locals_1': {'var': 'var!'}}
locals_3: {'var': 'var!', 'locals_1': {'var': 'var!'}, 'locals_2':{'var':'var!','locals_1': {'var': 'var!'}}}
```

The returns are simple dict objects, that capture the growing stages of the local namespace.
This is what I intended.

Other possible ways to copy `locals()` (here "L") are `dict(L)`, `copy.copy(L)` and `copy.deepcopy(L)`.

Answer (score 5):

Let's run this code:

```
def func():
  var = 'var!'
  locals_1 = locals()
  print(id(locals_1), id(locals()), locals())
  locals_2 = locals()
  print(id(locals_2), id(locals()), locals())
  locals_3 = locals()
  print(id(locals_3), id(locals()), locals())
  return locals_1, locals_2, locals_3


func()
```

This would be in the output:

```
44860744 44860744 {'locals_1': {...}, 'var': 'var!'}
44860744 44860744 {'locals_2': {...}, 'locals_1': {...}, 'var': 'var!'}
44860744 44860744 {'locals_2': {...}, 'locals_3': {...}, 'locals_1': {...}, 'var': 'var!'}
```

`locals()` here grows as expected, however you are assigning the *reference* to `locals()`, not the *value* of `locals()` to each variable.

After each assignment `locals()` **gets changed, but reference does not**, so each variable is pointing to the same object. In my output all object `id`s are equal, this is the proof.

**Longer explanation**

These variables has the same link (reference) to that object. Basically, all variables in Python are references (similar concept to pointers).

```
        locals_1            locals_2                 locals_3
            \                    |                      /
             \                   |                     /
              V                  V                    V
            ---------------------------------------------
            |            single locals() object         |
            ---------------------------------------------
```

They have absolutely no idea what value does `locals()` have, they only know where to get it when it's needed (when the variable is used somewhere). Changes on `locals()` don't affect those variables.

In the end of you function you're returning three variables, and this is what happening when you're printing them:

```
print(locals_N) -> 1. Get object referenced in locals_N
                   2. Return the value of that object
```

See? So, this is why they have exactly the same value, the one `locals()` has at the moment of `print`.

If you change `locals()` (somehow) again and then run print statements, what would be printed 3 times? Yep, the NEW value of `locals()`.

Comment: I'll have to study this, great, but I can still ask: why does locals_1 contain itself - I might expect it wouldn't?

Comment: @tfj, as @frostnational says, `locals_1` is not actually a separate dictionary from the one returned by `locals()`. Rather, it is a *reference* to the same dictionary. Changes to `locals()` will be reflected in `locals_1`. So when `local_1` is added to the scope, `locals_1` gains an entry that refers to itself.

Comment: @bgschiller, is "reference" the same thing as "identifier" (commonly, "name")? But why does locals() capture itself on the first try? By the time it's created, it's too late (I would have thought).

Comment: @tfj `locals_1` is a reference to `locals()` object. Then, `locals()` contains reference to itself and this is indeed an endless recursion.

Comment: @tfj "reference" is a similar idea to "pointer". You can think of `locals()` and `locals_1` as 'pointing' to the very same object in memory. So, when the value of `locals()` changes, `locals_1` gets the update automatically. There's no time-travel happening -- everything happens in the order you expect. It's just that by the time you go to print the value of `locals_1`, it looks different.

Comment: I think I see: by the time the func returns, all three 'variables'

Comment: ... (continuing) have been updated, in fact they all name the same object ("identifier" is an official Python term).

Answer (score 4):

I like your question, really good one.

Yes, `locals()` is sort of magic, but with your approach, you will get it soon or later and will love it.

## Key concepts

### Dictionary is assigned by reference and not by value

```
In [1]: a = {"alfa": 1, "beta": 2}

In [2]: b = a

In [3]: b
Out[3]: {'alfa': 1, 'beta': 2}

In [4]: b["gama"] = 3

In [5]: b
Out[5]: {'alfa': 1, 'beta': 2, 'gama': 3}

In [6]: a
Out[6]: {'alfa': 1, 'beta': 2, 'gama': 3}
```

As you see, `a` get changed indirectly at the moment `b` got modified, because both `a` and `b` are pointing to the same data structure in memory.

### `locals()` is returning dictionary with all local variables

Edit: clarified when is this dict updated

So all local variables existing at the moment of `locals()` call are living here. If you make subsequent calls to `locals()`, this dictionary is updated at the moment of the call.

## Answering your questions

### Why does locals_1 include itself?

Because `locals_1` is reference to dictionary of all locally defined variables. As soon as `locals_1` becames part of local namespace, it gets part of the dictionary `locals()` returned.

### Why does locals_1 include locals_2? Is locals_1 assigned when func is created, or executed?

The same answer as previous one applies.

### And why is locals_3 not included anywhere?

This is the most difficult part of your question. After some research I found excellent article about this topic: http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201211/tricky_locals.html

The fact is, that `locals()` returns a dictionary, which contains references to all local variables. But the tricky part is, it is not directly that structure, it is a dictionary, which is only updated at the moment, `locals()` is called.

This explains missing locals_3 in your result. All results are pointing to the same dictionary, but it does not get updated after you introduce `locals_3` variable.

When I added another print `locals()` before return, I found it there, without it not.

Uff.

### Does "{...}" indicate an 'endless recursion'? Sort of like those photos of mirrors facing each other?

I would read it as "there is something more". But I think, you are right, that this is a solution for printing recursive data structure. Without such a solution the dictionary could not be really printed in finite amount of time.

## Bonus - use of **locals() in string.format()

There is one idiom, where locals() are shortening your code a lot, in string.format()

```
name = "frost"
surname = "national"
print "The guy named {name} {surname} got great question.".format(**locals())
```

Comment: Just make sure you disable warning 0142 in Pylint if you use that last one, since it will complain about your use of "[black magic](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200806/pylint.html)"!

Answer (score 1):

frostnational and Jan Vlcinsky have already given good explanations of what happens behind the scenes. Here's a small addition on achieving the behavior that you originally expected. You can use the `copy` method to create a copy of the `locals()` dict. That copy will not be updated when `locals()` is updated, so it contains the "snapshot" that you expected:

```
In [1]: def func():
   ...:     var = 'var!'
   ...:     locals1 = locals().copy()
   ...:     locals2 = locals().copy()
   ...:     locals3 = locals().copy()
   ...:     return locals1, locals2, locals3
   ...:

In [2]: locals1, locals2, locals3 = func()

In [3]: locals1
Out[3]: {'var': 'var!'}

In [4]: locals2
Out[4]: {'locals1': {'var': 'var!'}, 'var': 'var!'}

In [5]: locals3
Out[5]:
{'locals1': {'var': 'var!'},
 'locals2': {'locals1': {'var': 'var!'}, 'var': 'var!'},
 'var': 'var!'}
```

As expected, each copy only contains the variables that have been defined before `locals()` is called.